# When you interact with bash (via graphical terminal) what file does bash read from in order to obtain user input?

Tags: operating-systems, ubuntu-18.04

This was a homework question and I've tried several Google searches but to no avail. Can someone help me understand the following answer ? Would someone be kind enough to direct me to an online resource which discusses tty. Thanks in advance

**A: It normally reads from a tty device such as /dev/pts/0 or similar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be studying
[devpts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devpts),
defined as:

> devpts is a virtual filesystem available in the Linux kernel since version 2.1.93 (April 1998). It is normally mounted at /dev/pts and contains solely device files which represent slaves to the multiplexing master located at /dev/ptmx.

In fact "pts" stands for "**p**seudo **t**erminal **s**lave".
It is purely virtual and resides in memory only,
existing only for graphical terminals that don't have real input terminals.

It is further defined as:

> A pseudoterminal ("pseudo TTY" or "PTY") is a pair of pseudo-devices –
> a slave and a master – that provide a special sort of communication
> channel. The slave pseudo-device emulates a physical computer text
> terminal, like e.g. the DEC VT100, it can read and write text as
> though it was such a physical terminal. The master pseudo-device
> provides the means by which a program providing a text-based user
> interface acts with and controls its slave. Widely spread programs
> with a text-based user interface are terminal emulators, e.g. xterm,
> gnome-terminal or Konsole, or programs using SSH or telnet. Writing to
> the master is exactly like typing on a terminal, thus the master
> pseudo-device acts kind of like the person sitting in front of the
> physical computer text terminal.

You will also find good information in the post
[Why are there so many /dev/tty in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/449781/why-are-there-so-many-dev-tty-in-linux)